# Update or add node to simplexml if type query

Tags: php, if-statement, simplexml

OK sorry about this, but getting knickers in twist with what is really a very simple task.  I have a simple xml structure:

```
<site>
<page>
 <pagename>page1</pagename>
  <title>title1</title>
  <id>abc
  <plot>
    this is text
  </plot>
  </id>
  </page>

 <page>
  <pagename>page2</pagename>
  <title>titlee2</title>
  <id>xyz
  <plot>
   this is text
  </plot>
  </id>
</page>
</site>
```

I pass 3 variables by ajax post from a form the variables are pagename, id and plot.

What I cannot seem to do is write the right query that checks the pagename node against the pagename variable, then checks for the id node in that page.  If the id node exists then I update the plot node, if the id does not exist I create the id node and the plot node.

I can write/update the nodes, somebody did help find the right page but then I get lost.  So in my example xml above if I pass the variables pagename=page1 and id=abc then I just update the plot, but if pagename is page1 and id=def (which does not exist) the I need to create the id and the plot.  as said can do the addChild, update bit, just cannot get the query right to check that the id exists for that page - note `$id = $site->xpath('//id[text()="'.$posted_variable.'"]');` doesn't work for me because the id might be present in more than one page node, but it cannot be duplicated in the same page node.

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

OK I have it working, may not be pretty but it does work -

```
$xml   = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');

$site  = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());

$paget = "index";

$text  = $_POST['tosave'];

$text  = htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

// EDIT / UPDATE //

$pages = $site->xpath('//page/pagename[text()="'.$paget.'"]/..');

if($pages){

$a = array();

foreach( $pages[0]->id as $ID ){

array_push($a,$ID);

}


if(in_array($_POST['containerid'],$a)){

    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {

        if($value==$_POST['containerid']){

        $pages[0]->id[$key]->plot = trim($text) ;

        }

    }

} else {

       $pages[0]->addChild('id',$_POST['containerid'])->addChild('plot',trim($text));

}

}

$site->asXML("xml.xml");

exit;
```